# Why am I getting an error whenever I run my function?

Tags: python

```
import turtle

def replaygame():
    replay_label = turtle.Turtle()
    replay_label.speed(0)
    replay_label.color("White")
    replay_label.penup()
    replay_label.setposition(-290,280)
    againornot = replay_label.textinput("Do you want to play again Y/N ?",False, align = "right", font = ("Arial" , 20, "normal"))
    if againornot == Y:
        True
    else:
        False

replaygame()
```

I'm not sure what the problem is. I imported turtle and I went through it twice. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nn/Documents/sfgh.py", line 189, in <module>
    replaygame()
  File "/Users/nn/Documents/sfgh.py", line 158, in replaygame
    againornot = replay_label.textinput("Do you want to play again Y/N ?",False, align = "right", font = ("Arial" , 20, "normal"))
AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'textinput'
```

Comment: Can you include an image of your error?

Comment: Try editing this line to put quotes around the Y.  againornot == ’Y’:

Comment: It's good practice on this site to include the full error traceback of any error(s) you get in the text of your question so that we can better understand how to help you, as different errors can have different causes and solutions

Answer (score 1):

When you have a minute, please post your error. In the meantime, I presume the error stems from here:

Try editing this line to put quotes around the Y. againornot == ’Y’

(Apologies for poor the formatting, I’m using my phone.)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this :

```
import turtle

def replaygame():
    replay_label = turtle
    replay_label.speed(0)
    replay_label.color("White")
    replay_label.penup()
    replay_label.setposition(-290,280)
    againornot = replay_label.textinput('Play Again', "Do you want to play again Y/N ?")
    if againornot == Y:
        True
    else:
        False

replaygame()
```